# Pros and Cons of having different WARs for server and client side and deploying them in different application servers

Tags: java, web-applications, architecture, jboss

We have a product in which the UI is packaged as a separate WAR and server is packaged as a separate WAR file. Right now both these WARs are deployed in the same app container. Below are the pros and cons of this approach that i have found:

Pros of having different wars:
1. I feel having two different WARs allows me the flexibility of refactoring either UI or server side code without affecting the other.
2. To maximize memory usage, i can deploy it in two different containers. so if earlier i was using 2 GB for the entire jboss (say i am using jboss), now i can potentially use 4 gb if deployed in two
    different jboss app servers (ofcourse different port no.)
3. I can scale my application. If tomorrow, i see that server is my bottleneck, then i could create a server farm,(for my server module only), since the server itself is a different WAR, without bothering about UI WAR.
4. Loosely coupled and gives me various integrations points

Cons:
1. For UI, i use primefaces. i do not see a use case where i could see an integration framework like seam adding value. Can someone tell me if having an integration framework would make sense
for my UI war? Basically, the whole fun of seam, is the wonderful integration that its provides with UI, EJB among other stuff. Therefore, i do not see too much value here because my form would ask the rest API to do all the processing.

Can someone tell me if having multiple wars actually help in scalability and maintenance. e.g.,one benefit that i see is that if i have two wars and i need to upgrade server platform, i do not need to bring down my UI. Any other benefit apart from what i have listed above?

Also, i want to understand if everything is packaged as an EAR, how would you scale specific layers of our architecture. As mentioned above, if i feel server layer is the bottleneck, in case of one WAR/EAR, how would i scale my application?

I am still not sure if i need to carry on with my model of different WARs in different application servers, or should i have just one WAR for my entire application? Please guide...

Comment: ok, we dont have EAR actually, just WARs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you backend if independent and you comunicate with client using some REST or SOAP web service - this is good. Try to imagine that tommorow you drop your client with java and create other one with .NET. Does backend need some changes? If not - this is good. If yes - I think it does not coast to have 2 wars.

Comment: yes, but what about the advantages. I am actually seeing a lot of advantages of having two WARs. What i want to understand is how can a single EAR/WAR file scale? I do not think if all the layers are packages in single WAR/EAR, they can scale vertically. Only horizontal scaling is possible, right? and i do not see horizontal scaling as an ideal form of scaling.

Comment: It look likes not vertical scaling, but you scale this two components horisontally with possible different scale: you can have 3 fronends and 20 backends for example. In case od single war - 25 backends to get same.

Comment: right alexey28, so that indeed makes having multiple WARs a superior alternative right ? and if yes, how does an application with single WAR claim to be scalable because most of the applications (so called scalable) that i have seen are deployed in single container as single WAR....

Comment: There can be two aproatch to scale: 1. Your own solution - you have some client that perform load balancing and have an addresses of registered backends at cluster (two wars). 2. You use existing clustering solution: building cluster of app server (Tomcat can do it I think) and use cluster of database servers. In this case NoSQL can be taken in account. But this is very responsable solution to use NoSQL (single war).

Comment: alexey29...i am sorry ...didnt get your perspective on NoSQL. In what case do you think it could be a replacement for RDBMS,if at all? Actually am still not very conversant with NoSQL concept...